# How to hide element with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What am I doing wrong in the following example?  The jquery code needs to go above the footer div in this case.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
#(document).ready(function(){
$('#footer').hide();
});
</script>

<div id="footer">testing footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand why this question get votes to close it. I'm learning JQuery and I won't do this error because I read this question.

Comment: Lots of very good questions get close votes.  Just ignore them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typo:

```
#(document).ready(function(){
```

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

You should see some sort of Error in your browser window (or console) if you use your current code.

Comment: Using FF with Firebug.  Didn't see any error.  I updated the code but the footer still isn't hiding.

Comment: @4thSpace well that is an odd predicament. Can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/NL6Uf/

Comment: @4thSpace works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NL6Uf/1/ You did not fix the typo in your version or include jQuery....

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I updated it and added the jquery library reference and it works.  Thanks.  I did update the OP code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @4thSpace well then you have some other issues going on...

Comment: I checked the source to your jsfiddle.  It is using $(window).load().  That is required in addition to $(document).ready()?

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML that you posted is /actually/ the code that you are testing? Don't you have another javascript references or code?

Comment: what happens if you replace `$` for `jQuery`?

Comment: It was actually a bad reference to the jquery library.  Works fine now.

Comment: @4thSpace you do **not** need `$(window).load(...)` in your code.

Comment: @Neal yes, I've confirmed.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem @4thSpace ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Actually the placement of the jQuery code has nothing to do with this working or not.

The problem is you are using an `#` instead of `$` to reference the jQuery object.  This code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
}
```